# Is 1 hour layover enough from Frankfurt-Albania?

Tags: transit, short-connections, fra

I travel with L.H. from Paris-Frankfurt-Albania.
It is one ticket with Lufthansa. 
I should arrive in Frankfurt at 19.40 and the flight to Albania is at 20.40
I already booked my ticket and I am now in panic if I can make it.
I will greatly appreciate your answer.

Thank you

Comment: Is it a single ticket?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas "It is one ticket with Lufthansa."

Comment: This is why I wanted a canonical "I bought a single ticket with a super short connection" question.

Comment: Perhaps.  Talk to your flight attendant after everything has settled down on the Paris-Frankfurt flight and he or she will at least let you know your options.